# How can I redirect without clicking? Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, onclick

I am using a system written in Laravel. When you click on the payment page, a picture with a "Pay" button appears. But after clicking there it redirects to the final payment page. How can I redirect this without clicking it? :/ help please

```
return sprintf('
            <form method="POST" action="%s" accept-charset="utf-8">
                %s
                %s
                <input type="image" src="//static.liqpay.ua/buttons/p1%s.radius.png" name="btn_text" />
            </form>
            ',
            $this->_checkout_url,
            sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />', 'data', $data),
            sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />', 'signature', $signature),
            $language
        );
    }
```

Comment: This is really not how to output HTML in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to redirect to what page you want.

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

If you want to redirect without loading the picture, simply remove the code that shows the image and put the redirect code.

Comment: This is how I need to direct it.
$this->_checkout_url,